# Transpose with NA

Tags: r

I have a file as like this

```
Name   Country  Count
Cat     NZ       103
Dog     NZ       234
Cat     AUS      2345
Cow     AUS      234
Dog     aus      231
Goat    IND      22345
```

and I am expecting an out put as like this

```
      Cat   Dog Cow Goat
 AUS  2345  231 243  NA
 NZ   103   234  NA  NA
 IND   NA   NA   NA  22345
```

I have tried with the melt function in R and but the challenge is with the small letter(aus) tag and the NA. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you add what has failed? maybe this `df %>% 
+   pivot_wider(2:ncol(.),names_from=Name, values_from=Count)`? Maybe first "clean" aus to AUS?

Comment: It is a big data set and I do not think it is possible to do toupper for all.

Comment: You can use a `map`ping/dict. Alternatively, look at string distance to calculate string similarity and use that for converting to `upper` (this is an overk*ll though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Country` to upper-case and transform data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Country = toupper(Country)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Count)

# Country   Cat   Dog   Cow  Goat
#  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 NZ        103   234    NA    NA
#2 AUS      2345   231   234    NA
#3 IND        NA    NA    NA 22345
```

Comment: Maybe arrange by country to match OP's?

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), toupper(Country) ~ Name)
```

-output

```
Country  Cat Cow Dog  Goat
1:     AUS 2345 234 231    NA
2:     IND   NA  NA  NA 22345
3:      NZ  103  NA 234    NA
```

---

Or use `acast` to match OP's output

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, toupper(Country) ~ Name)
```

-output

```
 Cat Cow Dog  Goat
AUS 2345 234 231    NA
IND   NA  NA  NA 22345
NZ   103  NA 234    NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Cow", "Dog", "Goat"
), Country = c("NZ", "NZ", "AUS", "AUS", "aus", "IND"), Count = c(103L, 
234L, 2345L, 234L, 231L, 22345L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `reshape`

```
reshape(
  transform(df, Country = toupper(Country)),
  idvar = "Country",
  timevar = "Name",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

gives

```
  Country Count.Cat Count.Dog Count.Cow Count.Goat
1      NZ       103       234        NA         NA
3     AUS      2345       231       234         NA
6     IND        NA        NA        NA      22345
```